# Possible to integrate jcodec's h264 encoder into red5-screenshare?

Tags: mp4, h.264, flv, remote-desktop, rtmp

I'm trying to minimize red5-screenshare's bandwith footprint by using jcodec's h264 encoder. The screenvideo codec takes up very little upload bandwidth, but only when used in 128 color mode. When used in full 24-bit RGB color mode it requires at least 5-10 Mbps on a lower resolution screen, which is unacceptable. I'm hoping that by using h264 I'd at least halve that upload bandwidth requirement.

To ask an actual question, would it be too hard to integrate jcodec into red5's screenshare, without having to rewrite the whole encoding and packaging process?
Keep in mind that I'd like to decode this video on the client side by using Adobe Flash Player.

---

Red5-screenshare: https://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/source/checkout

Jcodec: https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec

---

Also, could someone please give me some hints as to where I could find some info on how to approach this problem? I'm not very familiar with video codecs, encoding, decoding or packaging frames for streaming, so I'd appreciate some learning resources on that.

That would be all, thank you and have a good day!

Comment: My answer here may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/27558544/127938